# How to connect IRIS Health to local FHIR server

Tags: intersystems-iris

I want to know how I can connect IRIS Health to local FHIR server. I would like to implement a new feature.  Currently I am using HAPIFHIR Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRIS for Health has its own FHIR implementation.

And in any way, you can connect to any FHIR with its REST API, no matter from IRIS or something else.